# Installing Windows Server 2003 on a NAS?

Tags: windows-server-2003, raid, dell

Installing an operating system is not particularly hard. But for, the first time, I just can't seem to do it.

I have a Dell Powervault 745N. This is a rackmounted NAS with four hard drives (a RAID system). Now, this is Windows Server 2003 compatible, I know this for a fact.

The problem are the drivers for the hard drive. I have a lot of floppy disks with drivers on them (not sure what is what because my colleagues didn't really mark anything on some of the disks). When I want to install the driver, the installation tells me "it failed to install the driver". There is no further information, nor have my colleagues provided me with a disk that actually has the right driver.

I have manually downloaded the correct drivers from the Dell website (entering the service tag to be sure). They fail to install also. I have also searched google and all that, so, finally I turn to you, ServerFault users.

What is the sollution to this real pain of an installation?

Any help at all would be appreciated!!!
Thanks!!

Comment: Drivers for the RAID controller, you don't normally need drivers for the individual disks.

Comment: Hopefully you got the driver for Windows 2003?! And not for 2008. Service tag is a good hint. The right place to ask for help is the service support of Dell.

Comment: Yes, it's the driver for 2003, 2008 isn't supported for my machine (says so on the Dell Website). I downloaded once more the driver (SCSI RAID controller) and put them on an empty floppy...

Comment: no donuts, after trying to add the driver, the installation just tells me "..has failed to install..", i think it's time to contact Dell...

Comment: It's a purpose-built NAS, you probably can't install a plain-Jane OS on it at all. Look through the first document Joe linked you to : it's entitled "Reinstalling the Operating System on the Dell™ PowerVault™ 745N". Tells you what to do, and it's quite specific. It's not a standard OS install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should have a look here:

http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/stor-sys/spv745N/en/ts/PV745NTS.pdf

and here:

http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pvaul/en/pvaul_745n_specs.pdf

It looks to me like the supported OS is Windows Storage Server 2003, not Windows Server 2003.

Comment: Well, I will check with my colleagues if the company has a Storage Server 2003 installation cd, that might be it. The reason I didn't try that before: http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/osmatrix/index?c=us&cs=RC956904&l=en&s=hied If I select my server, this little menu shows me that Server 2003 is supported, so that is quite confusing...

Comment: We do not have a Storage Server 2003 installation cd... or the Resource cd for that matter, I guess this is a hard lesson to learn for our company: do not throw away documentation or disks that came with the server...
We do have cd's from an other dell server though, but they will definetely not help any installation process.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. As a last resort, I might suggest contacting Dell and getting some guidance from them.

Comment: Glad to help...